# Using Portable Python to copy text from an outside program and simulate keystrokes in Windows 7

Tags: python, automation, keystrokes

Now, I'm attempting to automate a little decompiler I have (turns assembly from a .gba file into pseudo C), as it currently requires that the user decompile each individual line (16 bits), which is rather tedious, considering that one of the files I want to fully decompile has 908132 lines of necessary code.

I'm very limited in my programming capabilities both in my own knowledge/experience and in that I don't have administrative rights on the computer due to it belonging to my stepfather, who recently passed away (and I don't have the password for his account, nor the money for a new computer that doesn't entirely suck.)

The decompiler itself is called pksvui, though I truly doubt that'll matter for anything other than routing. I know how to copy text with python, but I would like to know how to pull it from this specific program (simulating ctrl+a and ctrl+c might work if you can tell me how to make it specifically choose the program's textbox.)

The next step would be to paste it to a .txt file, but I have that covered.

I would then need the automation program to reselect the decompiler and simulate F8, then edit a text box value by adding 10 (as in 16, in hex), then simulate Enter

I tried to find each individual piece but, as you might expect from my name, I'm new at this.

Comment: This is too broad to get a good answer. People can help you with a specific issue you encounter in this process, but we can't solve your general programming difficulties, your computer being old, your lack of admin rights, etc.

Comment: I cited individual functions, such as selecting a tab, pulling strings from a specific textboxes, and simulating keystrokes. I put my problems in there to explain why I'm unable to do many things and to (hopefully) prevent suggestions that require I circumvent said issues.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an ideal task for some scripting with [Sikuli Script](http://www.sikuli.org/).

Sikuli let's you automate everything that you can do manually with a mouse and keybourd. It uses image recognition to find elements that you can interact with. Programming is done in Python (Jython) and with a special editor that allows for images to used in the source code.

Comment: I'll definitely check this out. Thank you!